# How to implement filters in multiple widget?

Tags: laravel

[image]

How can i implement filter function into multiple widget? i did apply the filter in dashboard but i can't function...anyone can give some advice? This is my filter codes

```
protected function getFormSchema(): array
    {
        return [
            \Filament\Forms\Components\Grid::make(2)
                ->schema([
                Group::make([
                    Select::make(name: 'warehouse')
                        ->options(Warehouse::query()->options())
                        ->reactive()
                        ->preload(),
                    DatePicker::make('from_date')
                        ->default(now()->subWeeks(2))
                        ->reactive(),
                    DatePicker::make('to_date')
                        ->default(now())
                        ->reactive(),
                ])->columnSpan(1),
            ])->columns(3),
        ];
    }
```